# Formatting Bootstrap links on Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a navigation bar at the top of my site, and aligned to the right a Log Out link only when the user is logged in. I have this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <%= link_to "Simpleref", root_path, :class => "navbar-brand" %>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <% ((user_signed_in?)? @nav_items_user : @nav_items).each do |i| %>
      <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(i[:url]) %>">
        <a href="<%= i[:url] %>" class="nav-link"><%= i[:name] %>
          <% if current_page?(i[:url]) %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span><% end %>
        </a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>

   <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <ul class = "nav pull-right">
    <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

What is wrong? I get a navbar with the Logout link to the left and higher than the references and home links.

Comment: You've forgot `<li>` tag before print Log out link.

Comment: thanks, very new to Ruby on Rails and web dev. that did not solve the problem, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```